# Heap of polynomials

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, heap

So I wanted to ask a data structures questions. For a given array if we need to work with max/min we work with heaps. It is only possible because the given data is constant. They do not change. What if the data is set of polynomials.

Following assumptions can be taken.

1. The polynomial is a linear equation of ax+b. And we have a large set of a and b.
2. a and b are only positive.

Basic requirements.

1. Changing values of certain a&b should be possible.
2. for a given x, we need a polynomial with maximum resultant.

Can you suggest me a data structure or guide me through. I am kind of stuck here.

Comment: I'm envisioning what you're doing as maintaining a set of lines and storing whichever segment has the highest y value at each point. I'm not sure how to do this efficiently, but I suspect there's a fast data structure or algorithm here.

Comment: Yeah , you got it right. I was actually thinking for polynomials, but then I thought lets get easier version than maybe I can generalize it. There has to be a data structure which can do this efficiently , because lines aren't random. They are pretty specific. Not constant but specific. So there has to be something which beats the regular O(n). At least for a large data set for many queries on x.

Comment: Are all the lines known in advance? Or do they change? In other words, are you mostly doing queries on points, or are you intermixing insertions, deletions, and lookups?

Comment: I am actually mixing insertion , deletions and even maybe modify certain lines ( if it is possible)